# geopandas contains method doesn't return polygons

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas

I Recently started using geopandas to handle shapefiles of my city. Recently I found a problem using the contains method from geopandas. The problem is the following:

I got 2 different shapefiles with the same crs projection: districts and sections. I need to obtain all the section polygons that are withing a district. I read about the contains method and it looks like it is exactly what I need but at the moment of running it, the returning polygons within is empty. The weird thing here is when I use intersects method instead contains it returns the sections within the district plus all the adjacent sections to this.

The following is my code:

```
districts = GeoDataFrame.from_file('districts_WGS84.shp')
sections = GeoDataFrame.from_file('sections_WGS84.shp')

districts.crs == sections.crs #To be sure the files share the same crs

#The following line returns an empty array, but it should return all seccions within a district
print len(sections[sections.contains(districts.geometry[34]) == True])
# districts.geometry[34] is a fixed discrict in order to run a test

#The following line returns the list of all sections within the district plus adjacent ones
print len(sections[sections.intersects(districts.geometry[34]) == True])
```

Is there any problem with how I'm trying to get it or is a problem with the method itself?

Here there are the shapefiles to repeat my problem:

Districts: https://ufile.io/0a6f1

Sections: https://ufile.io/e2463

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Intersect means that it will return true if the two polygons are overlapped, however contains means it will return true only if one polygon is totally within another one.